# Does anybody know a proof that the bases of two or more numbers with the same exponent can be multiplied together? (examples in the main text body).

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I.e. how can we simply assume that $5^{1/2}\times 6^{1/2} = 30^{1/2}$ (i.e. all we have done is multiplied the bases and applied the exponent to the answer).

In more general terms, how can we assume $a^e\times b^e = (ab)^e$?

Comment: Note that the statement assumes that $a>0,b>0$ perhaps one of $a,b$ is zero with $e>0$. The statement is not true if we allow negative $a,b$ and complex number results.

Comment: @RoryDaulton are you sure about that? For negative $a$ and positive $b$, both forms are positive for even integer $e$, negative for odd integer $e$, and undefined for $e=0$; the magnitude won't be affected by the signs of $a$ and $b$, and the sign of the result is the same in all these cases. For fractional $e$, both are negative if the denominator of $e$ is odd so that's still fine; if the denominator is even, then they are both imaginary but I believe they will still be equal by properties of surds. It's hard to call the undefined cases "equal", but they are at least undefined together...

Comment: @lvc: One famous example is $(-1)^{1/3}\cdot(-1)^{1/3}$. In complex numbers, $(-1)^{1/3}=\frac 12+\frac{\sqrt 3}2i$, so the product I gave is $-\frac 12+\frac{\sqrt 3}2i$, but $(-1\cdot -1)^{1/3}=1^{1/3}=1$. Note that I said "complex number results" in my previous comment.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I see. So, would it be true with the slightly weaker condition than yours that both sides are defined and real?

Answer (score 5):

For integer exponents, this is easily proved by induction in high school. For a more general (real) exponent, you start from the definition of exponent $e$:
$$a^e b^e\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\exp(e\ln a)\exp(e\ln b)=\exp\bigl(e(\ln a+\ln b)\bigr)=\exp\bigl(e\ln(ab)\bigr)\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}(ab)^e.$$

Comment: You meant $\exp((e\ln a + \color{red}{e}\ln b))$ or $\exp(e(\ln a + \ln b))$.

Comment: Oops!  One more typo for my collection! Thank you for pointing it. It's corrected now.

Comment: @BagelEnthusiast: Is $e$ supposed to be an integer? If not, how do you define $a^{\tfrac1n}$?

Comment: Wow, I'm a moron; this question was posted before I knew what e was (as in 2.71....) and I thought e meant 'any real exponent.' Apologies for the confusion...

Answer (score 0):

Start with the specific case of positive integer $e$, and generalise from there, up to at least rational $e$ (and possibly beyond; but note that this property *isn't* true in general for complex $e$). For this case you have (by definition):

$$a^e = a \times a \times a ... \times a \,\,\, (e \text{ times}) $$

So you have:

$$(ab)^e = (ab) \times (ab) \times (ab) ... \times (ab) \,\,\, (e \text{ times})$$

and:

$$a^eb^e = a \times a \times a ... \times a \times b \times b ... \times b \,\,\, (e \text{ times of both } a \text{ and } b)$$

These are equal because multiplication is both associative and commutative, which together imply that we can reorder things as we please.

You can extend this to negative integer $e$ by treating $a^e$ as the fraction $\frac{1}{a^{-e}}$, and applying the above argument to the denominator. Similarly, it extends to fractional $e$ by taking it as a surd, and you can prove $\sqrt[n] a \sqrt[n] b = \sqrt[n]{ab}$ by raising both sides to the $n$, and again applying the positive integer case of $a^eb^e = (ab)^e$ to note that the results are equal, which means both sides must be equal since we define $\sqrt[n] a$ to be the positive root for such $n$ where that matters.

Comment: What if $e$ is irrational?

Comment: @user170039 I must confess to not having come across irrational exponents before.  A quick search for how they work brings up, for example,  [this explanation](http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52857.html) that you approximate them by increasingly accurate rational $e$ and noting that that sequence converges. I suspect that since my argument would apply to every element in the sequence, it would also apply to the limit they converge to, but I don't know whether that is rigorous.